Deliquent town taxes
If I have delinquent in paying taxes in my town (didn't know I had it only thought I had state) and I play catch up this year, can I claim all that I payed this year or can I just claim the current years payment on my federal/state income taxes?

You can deduct state and local real estate taxes (but not penalties or interest) in the year they were paid if they meet certain criteria:

Must be levied annually (even if paid more frequently)
Must be for the general welfare
Not for a privilege or service specific to you

Also note that you will still be subject to the $10k State and Local Tax (SALT) maximum deduction ($5k each if married filing separately), and it only makes sense to itemize if the total deductions are more than the standard deduction amount.

the SALT maximum applies to schedule A deduction, but not to schedule E deduction, in case it's not clear.
